# "Unauthorized" when attempting to send email with SendGrid in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid

Not sure what's going on but every time I try to send an email i'm met with a error message.  I've literally tried everything I can think of and Nothing. This is the message i'm receiving from postman when I hit the localhost:4000/api/send-mail route.  I've been trying to work through this for hours now, if anyone can help that would be amazing.  Thanks in advance!!!

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "code": 401,
    "response": {
        "headers": {
            "server": "nginx",
            "date": "Mon, 21 Mar 2022 01:57:04 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "content-length": "116",
            "connection": "close",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "https://sendgrid.api-docs.io",
            "access-control-allow-methods": "POST",
            "access-control-allow-headers": "Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl",
            "access-control-max-age": "600",
            "x-no-cors-reason": "https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=600; includeSubDomains"
        },
        "body": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked",
                    "field": null,
                    "help": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

my user controllers code

```
const expressAsyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const generateToken = require("../../config/token/generateToken");
const User = require("../../model/user/User");
const validateMongodbId = require("../../utils/validateMongodbID");

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SEND_GRID_API_KEY);

//-------------------------------------
//Register
//-------------------------------------

const userRegisterCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  //Check if user Exist
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req?.body?.email });

  if (userExists) throw new Error("User already exists");
  try {
    //Register user
    const user = await User.create({
      firstName: req?.body?.firstName,
      lastName: req?.body?.lastName,
      email: req?.body?.email,
      password: req?.body?.password,
    });
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

//-------------------------------
//Login user
//-------------------------------

const loginUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  //check if user exists
  const userFound = await User.findOne({ email });
  //Check if password is match
  if (userFound && (await userFound.isPasswordMatched(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: userFound?._id,
      firstName: userFound?.firstName,
      lastName: userFound?.lastName,
      email: userFound?.email,
      profilePhoto: userFound?.profilePhoto,
      isAdmin: userFound?.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(userFound?._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Invalid Login Credentials");
  }
});

//------------------------------
//Users
//-------------------------------
const fetchUsersCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers);
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

//------------------------------
//Delete user
//------------------------------
const deleteUsersCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  //check if user id is valid
  validateMongodbId(id);
  try {
    const deletedUser = await User.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.json(deletedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

//----------------
//user details
//----------------
const fetchUserDetailsCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  //check if user id is valid
  validateMongodbId(id);
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

//------------------------------
//User profile
//------------------------------

const userProfileCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  validateMongodbId(id);
  try {
    const myProfile = await User.findById(id);
    res.json(myProfile);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

//------------------------------
//Update profile
//------------------------------
const updateUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req?.user;
  validateMongodbId(_id);
  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    _id,
    {
      firstName: req?.body?.firstName,
      lastName: req?.body?.lastName,
      email: req?.body?.email,
      bio: req?.body?.bio,
    },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
    }
  );
  res.json(user);
});

//------------------------------
//Update password
//------------------------------

const updateUserPasswordCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  //destructure the login user
  const { _id } = req.user;
  const { password } = req.body;
  validateMongodbId(_id);
  //Find the user by _id
  const user = await User.findById(_id);

  if (password) {
    user.password = password;
    const updatedUser = await user.save();
    res.json(updatedUser);
  } else {
    res.json(user);
  }
});

//------------------------------
//following
//------------------------------

const followingUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  //1.Find the user you want to follow and update it's followers field
  //2. Update the login user following field
  const { followId } = req.body;
  const loginUserId = req.user.id;

  //find the target user and check if the login Id exists
  const targetUser = await User.findById(followId);

  const alreadyFollowing = targetUser?.followers?.find(
    (user) => user?.toString() === loginUserId.toString()
  );
  if (alreadyFollowing) throw new Error("You are already folliwig this user");

  //1. Find the user you want to follow and update it's followers field
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    followId,
    {
      $push: { followers: loginUserId },
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  //2. Update the login user following field
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    loginUserId,
    {
      $push: { following: followId },
      isFollowing: true,
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.json("You are now following this user");
});

//------------------------------
//unfollow
//------------------------------

const unfollowUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { unFollowId } = req.body;
  const loginUserId = req.user.id;

  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    unFollowId,
    {
      $pull: { followers: loginUserId },
      isFollowing: false,
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    loginUserId,
    {
      $pull: { following: unFollowId },
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  res.json("You have successfully unfollowed this user");
});

//------------------------------
//Block Users
//------------------------------
const blockUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  validateMongodbId(id);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
      isBlocked: true,
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.json(user);
});

//------------------------------
//Block user
//------------------------------

const unBlockUserCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  validateMongodbId(id);

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
      isBlocked: false,
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.json(user);
});

//------------------------------
// Account Verification - Send email
//------------------------------
const generateVerificationTokenCtrl = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //build your message
    const msg = {
      to: "MizTamaraAndrea@gmail.com",
      from: "Tamara18_1985@msn.com",
      subject: "My first Node js email sending",
      text: "I hope this goes through",
    };

    await sgMail.send(msg);
    res.json("Email sent");
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});

module.exports = {
  generateVerificationTokenCtrl,
  userRegisterCtrl,
  loginUserCtrl,
  fetchUsersCtrl,
  deleteUsersCtrl,
  fetchUserDetailsCtrl,
  userProfileCtrl,
  updateUserCtrl,
  updateUserPasswordCtrl,
  followingUserCtrl,
  unfollowUserCtrl,
  blockUserCtrl,
  unBlockUserCtrl,
};
```

My user Routes Code

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  userRegisterCtrl,
  loginUserCtrl,
  fetchUsersCtrl,
  deleteUsersCtrl,
  fetchUserDetailsCtrl,
  userProfileCtrl,
  updateUserCtrl,
  updateUserPasswordCtrl,
  followingUserCtrl,
  unfollowUserCtrl,
  blockUserCtrl,
  unBlockUserCtrl,
  generateVerificationTokenCtrl,
} = require("../../controllers/users/usersCtrl");
const authMiddleware = require("../../middleware/auth/authMiddleware");

const userRoutes = express.Router();

userRoutes.post("/register", userRegisterCtrl);
userRoutes.post("/login", loginUserCtrl);
userRoutes.post("/send-mail", generateVerificationTokenCtrl);
userRoutes.get("/", authMiddleware, fetchUsersCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/password", authMiddleware, updateUserPasswordCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/follow", authMiddleware, followingUserCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/unfollow", authMiddleware, unfollowUserCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/block-user/:id", authMiddleware, blockUserCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/unblock-user/:id", authMiddleware, unBlockUserCtrl);
userRoutes.get("/profile/:id", authMiddleware, userProfileCtrl);
userRoutes.put("/:id", authMiddleware, updateUserCtrl);
userRoutes.delete("/:id", deleteUsersCtrl);
userRoutes.get("/:id", fetchUserDetailsCtrl);

module.exports = userRoutes;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have one of two problems here. Either, your API key does not have the permission to send messages, or has been deleted. Create yourself a new API key that has permission to send emails and try again.

Or, I see you appear to be trying to send from an `msn.com` email address. In order to send from a third party domain like that, you need to have set up [single sender verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification). This lets SendGrid know that you do have access to that email address and that you are not trying to spoof someone else's.

(Note that when you ship to production, we recommend you use your own domain and [authenticate that domain with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication), which will give you much better deliverability.)

Comment: Yes, it had something to do with my API KEY.  when placed in my .env file for some reason it wont work.  when hard coded, it works fine.  I have other key's in my .env file  that are working fine, so i'm not sure why the SendGrid API key won't work in there.  I'll have to figure it out, because they key can't stay hard coded.

Comment: Ok, that's a start! How are you putting it in your `.env` file? And where are you loading the dotenv library? You need to make sure that the variables in the `.env` file are loaded before the files that use the environment variables.

Comment: I figured it out…smh.  In my server.js file called dotenv config after my dbconnect (or the other way around I don’t remember lol). Well it didn’t like it so I moved the dotenv config well above it and it worked fine after that

Comment: Yep, make sure that the first thing your application loads is your environment config! Glad you got this sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that after my azure subscription was suspended, even though it was subsequently re-activated and all of the sendgrid configuration was just fine and looked normal, I consistently received the unauthorized response. After much looking around and fiddling I switched the sendgrid plan to the free plan and then back again and hey presto, everything worked again!